# Ubuntu not loading after deleting environment variables from file

Tags: boot, reboot

I have mistakenly deleted all the environment variables from a file by running the following command and restarted my Ubuntu 16.04.

> sudo gedit /etc/environment

Now,  it is loading and showing black screen and doing nothing. How can fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Hmm,  I don't think so :(

Comment: I flagged it as a duplicate because answers to that question describe what to do: specifically, boot to a Ubuntu install disk or USB stick, mount the hard drive, and edit /etc/environment to fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot the installation media, choose "Try Ubuntu", mount your root filesystem in `/mnt`, copy `/etc/environment` to `/mnt/etc/` (use `sudo cp -a` to preserve timestamps, ownership and access mode), unmount `/mnt` and reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the contents of my stock /etc/environment file from an Ubuntu 16.04 installation. It is only one line setting your PATH variable. Without knowing where to look for commands, that could definitely halt your boot. Can you add the below line to your /etc/environment file so it is the only line and see if it boots? Did your /etc/environment file only have one line in the beginning?

`PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`

Comment: Yes,  this was the line that removed.  Now,  problem is how can I add this line?  Without having a UI? Or filesystem access!!

Comment: @Nomi Follow the information that we have given you. Boot a liveCD and mount your drive. Edit the file in question. Done.

Comment: Yes, that would be how to edit the file on your install.  Please let us know how it goes!